# Rails doesn't set locale in url when I use redirect_to some_path(locale: :default_locale)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, localization, rails-i18n

I use routes like this:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{AVAILABLE_LANGAUGES_AS_STRING}/, defaults: {locale: "en"} do
etc
```

So I show a locale in an url like this:
/de/some-page

And I need to do a redirection from a controller to some page with locale:

```
redirect_to some_page_path(locale: :de, some_param: 'value')
```

But it doesn't include a default 'en' locale into an url when I use the redirect_to with locale: :en.
How to make the redirect_to method to include a default locale into an url and still use defaults: {locale: "en"} in the routes?